# Interview Question: Can we have an echo before header?

Tags: php, header, echo

I appeared for php test, their I was asked one question for which I could not find the answer.

The question is like this.

```
echo "MESSI is injured!!";
header("Location:somepage.php");
```

Interviewer want both **header** and **echo** to be written on the same page.

I wonder how's it possible.It should give some error like

***headers already sent by (output started at .....***

Is it really possible to write echo and header onto same page !!!

Comment: What php test is that? What is it for? Sorry to be nosy.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [Output Buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php) as

```
ob_start();
echo "MESSI is injured!!";
header("Location:somepage.php");
ob_end_flush();
```

The problem is that we cannot send the header after we start sending the output. To solve this we buffer the output. The function `ob_start` turns output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer. So the `echo` output will be buffered. Next we send the header without any problem as we've not yet spit out any output. Finally we call `ob_end_flush` to flush the internal buffer contents and to stop output buffering.

Comment: Actually if you have output buffering on, *nothing* will be sent before you flush it. Not even headers. (iirc)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as long as all the header calls come before any non-header output is sent (this includes pesky things like newlines/whitespace).  So

```
<?php
header("Location:somepage.php");
echo "MESSI is injured!!";
?>
```

should do the trick

Comment: Dosen't quite answer the question: write echo “” **and then** header()