# Using ob_start() to redirect to another page

Tags: php, redirect, pdo, buffer

I was trying to post data to my database using PHP PDO from a form with `action.php` as the action. However, I couldn't redirect back to `index.php` once the data has been posted successfully, unless I used `ob_start()` at the beginning of `action.php`. Here is my code:

```
<?php
ob_start(); 
include('dbconfig.php');

$id = $_POST['id']; 
$name = $_POST['name']; 

if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo('Please fill out the form!'); 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
} else {
    // Some statement using PHP PDO here 
    echo ('Data has been submitted'); 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
}?>
```

For all I know, `ob_start()` is used to turn on output buffering, so my question is:

1. Why do I have to use that?
2. Do I have to add `ob_end_clean()` at the end of the file?

Comment: You cannot echo before setting a header. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interview Question: Can we have an echo before header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766353/interview-question-can-we-have-an-echo-before-header)

Comment: Yes, but why using `ob_start()` solved the problem?

Comment: Headers must be set before body output. Simply put your `header` calls before any output.

Comment: `ob_start()` suppresses the echo's output, of course. It's clearly described in the manual. Read it more carefully.