# PHP Contact Form w/ verification & Paypal

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

the objective is to have a customer fill a form

then hit submit to which will send an email

then a message will appear

then a redirect to a simple paypal payment which is all hidden

i cannot get the page to open to paypal

```js
<? php

// configure
$name = $_POST['name'];
$from = 'contact <demo@domain.com>';
$sendTo = 'NEWCONTACT<new@gmail.com>';
$subject = 'New contact';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email', 'residence' => 'Residence', 'qualification' => 'Qualification', 'marital' => 'Marital', 'children' => 'Children', 'income' => 'Income', 'asset' => 'Asset', 'phone' => 'phone', 'nationality' => 'Nationality', 'interested' => 'interested', 'occupation' => 'Occupation', 'soccupation' => 'Spouse Occupation', 'SpouseEducationalQualification' => 'SpouseEducationalQualification', 'history' => 'History', 'source' => 'Source', 'comments' => 'Comments'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you '.$name.
', I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
// let's do the sending

try {
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
      $emailText. = "<pre>".
      "$fields[$key]: $value".
      "</pre>";
    }
  }

  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: '.$from,
    'Reply-To: '.$from,
    'Return-Path: '.$from,
  );

  mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

  $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  echo $encoded;
} else {
  echo $responseArray['message'];
}

$query_data = array(
    'amount' => '900',
    'business' => 'uaetousavisa@gmail.com',
    'cmd' => '_xclick',
    'currency_code' => 'USD',
    'item_number' => $_POST['item_number'],
    'item_name' => $_POST['item_name']
);

// redirect to PayPal
header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/?'.http_build_query($query_data));
```

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="form_name" name="name" type="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="form_email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required="required" data-error="Email is required.">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="income" type="text" name="income" placeholder="Net Monthly Income">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default more-get" name="buy">Submit</button>
    <div class="messages"></div>


</form>
```

and the php

Answer (score 1):

You are sending mixed instructions in the HTTP headers.

While you *can* send both body data and a redirect header, it's pretty pointless as the redirect will be followed.

But the real problem is that you are sending data (`echo ...`) before setting the redirect header (`header: location....');` - you must send all headers before output.

If you really want to echo data in this order, follow the hack here: [Interview Question: Can we have an echo before header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766353/interview-question-can-we-have-an-echo-before-header)