# Modal not showing up after login in php

Tags: javascript, php

My modal is not showing up after I add `header(location: homepage.php)` but modal is working fine if I remove the `header`. How can I possibly do it? I've also tried using echo for alert and same thing happens, so I don't know what is wrong with my code. I hope someone can help me thank you!. Here is my code

login.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $object = new Login();
    $object->getCredentials($email, $password);
}
?>

<form  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
<div>
 <label><b>EMAIL ADDRESS</b></label>
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></input>
</div>

<div>
 <label><b>PASSWORD</b></label>
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

processlogin.php

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
class Login
{
  public function getCredentials($email, $password)
  {     
    $email = $email;
    $password = $password;

    $object = new Db();
    $stmt = $object->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->execute([$email]);
    $stmtFetch = $stmt->fetch();

    if($stmt->rowCount()==1 && $stmtFetch['email'] == $email && $stmtFetch['password'] == $password)
    {
      echo "<script>$('#loginsuccess').modal('show')</script>";
      header("location: homepage.php");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something that might interest you here:
[Interview Question: Can we have an echo before header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766353/interview-question-can-we-have-an-echo-before-header)

The problem is that we cannot send the header after we start sending the output, and if you send the header before the `echo`, the `echo` will not be executed.

**Try this:**
*Solution 1: (from the link above).*

```
ob_start();
echo "<script>$('#loginsuccess').modal('show')</script>";
header("location: homepage.php");
ob_end_flush();
```

*Solution 2: Use a javascript redirection instead of header function.*

```
echo "<script>
        $('#loginsuccess').modal('show');
        window.location.replace('http://fullpath-homepage.php');
      </script>";
```

**Additional note:**
You can use also:

```
window.location.href="http://example.com";
window.location.assign("http://example.com");
```

The `replace` method navigates to the URL without adding a new record to the history.

Comment: sorry I just got home. the Solution 2 actually works. but it only shows the modal in a blink of an eye. Tried `await sleep(2000);` but it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: FOUND THE ANSWER

I use Yeti82's answer and this is what I did to make the delay to show modal of success and then directing to the next page.

```
echo "<script>
        $('#loginsuccess').modal('show'); 

        setTimeout(function() {window.location.href=\"homepage.php\";}, 1000);

        </script>";
```